# Difference between loading my trained model in a pretrained model and loading it in not pretrained one?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I trained an `Inception_v3` for my task. I have 3 classes.
After training I try to test my trained model and I use following code to load my model:

```
model = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True, aux_logits=False)  
model.fc = nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, 3)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(My Model Path.pth))
```

Download a **pretrained** Inception_v3, change output features and load my weight in this model.
I obtained very good results as I expect from validation phase.

If I use the same code but with pretrained=**False** the test go very bad.

```
model = models.inception_v3(pretrained=False, aux_logits=False)  
model.fc = nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, 3)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(My Model Path.pth))
```

Since in the model I download I load my weights, there should be no difference between pretrained True or False.

Does anyone know what changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pretrained=True` has an additional effect on the `inception_v3` model: it controls whether or not the input will be

> preprocessed according to the method with which it was trained on
> ImageNet

(source-code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/3852b41975702cb683a92c8e37f1ef74fd6a79b1/torchvision/models/inception.py#L43-L45)).

When you set `pretrained=False`, if you want to make things comparable at test time, you should also set `transform_input=True`:

```
model = models.inception_v3(pretrained=False, aux_logits=False, transform_input=True)  
model.fc = nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, 3)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(My Model Path.pth))
```

In case you're wondering, this is the [preprocessing](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/3852b41975702cb683a92c8e37f1ef74fd6a79b1/torchvision/models/inception.py#L133-L139):

```py
def _transform_input(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    if self.transform_input:
        x_ch0 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 0], 1) * (0.229 / 0.5) + (0.485 - 0.5) / 0.5
        x_ch1 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 1], 1) * (0.224 / 0.5) + (0.456 - 0.5) / 0.5
        x_ch2 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 2], 1) * (0.225 / 0.5) + (0.406 - 0.5) / 0.5
        x = torch.cat((x_ch0, x_ch1, x_ch2), 1)
    return x
```